# Relation between coefficients of two different power series.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} = a_nz^n, a_n\in\Bbb{C}$$ has a radius of convergence $\rho$. Then we can write $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} b_n (z-\frac{\rho}{2})^n$ for $\{z: |z-\dfrac{\rho}{2}|<\dfrac{\rho}{2}\}$.

Now, my question is if I can express $b_n$-s in terms of $a_n$-s by doing a binomial expansion and then changing the order of summation in the double sum? If yes, is it justified because the power series is absolutely convergent inside the radius of convergence? If no, is there an easy counterexample ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can: $$b_n = \sum_{m\ge 0} {m+n \choose m} a_{m+n} (\rho/2)^m $$

And yes, absolute convergence justifies the change of order.